# How to add a polygon to multipolygon geometry in NetTopologySuite?

Tags: polygon, topology, .net, nettopologysuite

I am missing something which seems obvious but does anyone know the answer?
I have tried 'Append' method on MultiPolygon with Polygon geometry parameter but nothing happens.
Would prefer to preserve initial MultiPolygon object with added new polygon.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a collection with the polygons of the roiginal MultiPolygon and the new polygon, and create a new MultiPolygon with it.

You can also use the Union() method, that should return a Multipolygon.